# Improving the performance of animated sprites in three.js

Tags: performance, animation, three.js, sprite

Right now I'm working on an online game and have decided to use webgl rather than HTML5's canvas for performance reasons. I'm using the three.js framework and my intention is to have moving animated sprites. The sprites themselves are placed on spritesheets and I use the UVOffset and UVScale to use the right art and switch the Sprite's art during time passing by. I was wondering whether there's a way to improve the performance of this code, because right now it starts to slow down at around 300 "players" on the field at the same time.

Regards

The following is the most important part of my code:

```
var image = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/idlew.png" );

  function addPlayer(){
    var mesh = new THREE.Sprite({map:image});//, affectedByDistance: false, useScreenCoordinates: false});
    images.push(mesh);
    mesh.position.set(Math.floor(Math.random() * 500), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500), 10);
    scene.add(mesh);
    mesh.uvScale.x = 96/1152;
    mesh.scale.x = 0.1;
    mesh.scale.y = 0.1;
  }


var imgBackground  = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/grass.jpg')
  });


   var background = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000),imgBackground);


  scene.add(background);



  scene.add(camera);
camera.rotation.x = -(Math.PI/2);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF));

addPlayer();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  var moveUp = false;
  tick();
  var ticker = 0;
  var usedOne = 0;

  function tick(){
    ticker++;
    if(ticker%10==0){
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].uvOffset.x = usedOne * 0.0835;
      };
        usedOne++;
        if(usedOne == 12) usedOne = 0;
        addPlayer();
        addPlayer();
        addPlayer();
        console.log(images.length);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( tick );

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and glad you sorted the problem out! So you know, it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question in the answers section below and (after a brief waiting period) mark it as the accepted answer. This helps other people who might run into the same issue in the future find the solution faster.

Answer (score 9):

I have written an example of code to display an animated texture, live example at:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

with source available at:

http://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

The useful part is a function I wrote to handle the offsets automatically.  The function (extracted from the link above) is as follows:

```
function TextureAnimator(texture, tilesHoriz, tilesVert, numTiles, tileDispDuration) 
{   
    // note: texture passed by reference, will be updated by the update function.

    this.tilesHorizontal = tilesHoriz;
    this.tilesVertical = tilesVert;

    // how many images does this spritesheet contain?
    //  usually equals tilesHoriz * tilesVert, but not necessarily,
    //  if there at blank tiles at the bottom of the spritesheet. 
    this.numberOfTiles = numTiles;
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    texture.repeat.set( 1 / this.tilesHorizontal, 1 / this.tilesVertical );

    // how long should each image be displayed?
    this.tileDisplayDuration = tileDispDuration;

    // how long has the current image been displayed?
    this.currentDisplayTime = 0;

    // which image is currently being displayed?
    this.currentTile = 0;

    this.update = function( milliSec )
    {
        this.currentDisplayTime += milliSec;
        while (this.currentDisplayTime > this.tileDisplayDuration)
        {
            this.currentDisplayTime -= this.tileDisplayDuration;
            this.currentTile++;
            if (this.currentTile == this.numberOfTiles)
                this.currentTile = 0;
            var currentColumn = this.currentTile % this.tilesHorizontal;
            texture.offset.x = currentColumn / this.tilesHorizontal;
            var currentRow = Math.floor( this.currentTile / this.tilesHorizontal );
            texture.offset.y = currentRow / this.tilesVertical;
        }
    };
}
```

You can initialize the material using (for example):

```
var runnerTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/run.png' );
// a texture with 10 frames arranged horizontally, display each for 75 millisec
annie = new TextureAnimator( runnerTexture, 10, 1, 10, 75 ); 
var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: runnerTexture } );
```

and update it before each render using:

```
var delta = clock.getDelta(); 
annie.update(1000 * delta);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Definitely a nice way to handle the offset changing automatically; however I don't really see how this could make the rendering faster. Right now I'm at a point where I have the application with an upper limit of 20fps (that being the sweetspot) and the sprites moving (x and y val) every frame, the animation changing (the offset changing) every 10 moves. The rendering redone every frame-change. The issue I have now is that the rendering goes too slow when I have too many sprites on my field...having 100 sprites moving and changing UV-offset while moving the camera gets extremely slow

Comment: +1 I filled my viewport with sprites (476 of them) all with transparency and 8 frames of animation. Using this method I was still getting 30+ fps. Thanks!

Comment: hi. I wrote another implementation of same idea, and pack it as module. I'm also use uv offset, but move all calculations to shaders. what do you think? https://github.com/elephanter/AnimatedSprites

Comment: Using imagemagick's standard geometry to combine frames into a single spritesheet, it needs to be read left-to-right, top-to-bottom. In order to make this compatible, I modified the Y position in the update method: `texture.offset.y = 1 - (currentRow / this.tilesVertical) - (1 / this.tilesVertical);`

Comment: @crowjonah - yeah I noticed that, your code is useful thanks.  Also Lee's explosion jpg file has sub-image sequencing from bottom right to top left but his code expects sequence to run from bottom left to top right.  The resulting animation is not smooth.

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question by realizing the code could be greatly improved by placing the

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Code in the right place so it was only called **when needed**.